# How do you remove the search box on the search results page?

Tags: theming, search

I'm working on customizing my search results page. By default, the results page contains another instance of the search box at the top. I have the search box in a block at the top of every page, so it's just cluttering things up on the results page. I have already overridden the two template files, but I don't see anything in there that outputs the second search box. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple approach to work within your theme, without requiring a dedicated module:

add to your template.php file...

```
function YOURTHEME_page_alter(&$page)
{
  if (arg(0) == 'search')
  {
    if (!empty($page['content']['system_main']['search_form']))
    {
      hide($page['content']['system_main']['search_form']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Beauty.  This is exactly what I was looking for!  Simple solution, too.  I'm sure @coreyp_1's solution would work as well, but I didn't want to have to make a full module.  Thanks to both answerers!

Answer (score 4):

This is a fun one... The Search box is returned as part of the render array returned by `search_view()`.

I suggest that you make a `hook_menu_alter()` which replaces the default callback for the search page with your own, which is basically a pass-thru to the core function, but that unsets the search form.  Something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['search']['page callback'] = 'MYMODULE_search_view';
}

function MYMODULE_search_view($module = NULL, $keys = '') {
  $build = search_view($module, $keys);
  unset($build['search_form']);
  return $build;
}
```

Don't forget to clear your cache to pick up the new hook and menu changes.

You may need to add additional paths to the `hook_menu_alter()` as needed (e.g., if you search users, then you may need to add entries for `search/user` and `search/user/%menu_tail`).